# How to contain floating element that is larger than it's parent?

Tags: html, css

Edit: overflow:auto to the parent did it. Thanks!

I have a parent element with flexible height. I also have a float:left image inside it.

```
<div>
    <img style="float:left;"/>
    Text goes here
</div>
```

Problem: The parent doesn't adjust it's height accordingly to the floating image's size. It needs to float because it needs to wrap text around it, and sometimes the text area is smaller than the image.

Is there any non-scripted workaround for this?

edit: I do not want to hide the overflow. I want the image to be visible.

Comment: @FahadHasan — That's how we achieved the same effect as `float` in 1995. We've had CSS for almost two decades now though.

Comment: You want your DIV to float left with the image dictating the divs height? Why even have the div at all.  Just get rid of the div and float the image.  Sorry, what needs to float to have text wrap around it?  The image or the div?

Comment: @ntgCleaner - I want the text to go around the image. To achieve that, I need to float the image to the left. But when I did that, the image went beyond the parent element sometimes. Anyway, the question has been answered in the duplicate thread.

Comment: One of the easiest ways to address it is to display the `div` as a `table` or `inline-block`.  Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/raposeqz/.

Comment: @Quentin: the post you've provided does not cover all possible solutions.  There are other easier methods besides clearfixing or setting `overflow: hidden` to "fix" the floats.  Besides, CSS is always changing and to assume that the past posts contain the most optimal solutions is ludicrous.  I think a better approach is to provide the link to the existing solutions in the comments and if people have other better approaches, then those could be provided as answers.

Comment: @DRD — Feel free to give additional answers on the duplicate question. I've never found anything easier than `overflow: hidden`, it is 25 characters as has fewer side effects then any other approach (changing the display as you suggest will alter the container's width for starters). Stackoverflow aims to have one canonical question page for each question, it can then have lots of answers - it is ludicrous to expect people to have to hunt through lots of different pages

Comment: @Quentin: you do have a point.  The whole process could have been a bit more practical.  In order to find a canonical question, a potential OP needs to know proper terms, which is unlikely for most newbies.  The title of the post to which you referenced does not capture the heart of the matter which is clearing of floats.  And, interestingly, that post does not include an `overflow: hidden` solution.  Redundancy does have its uses.